# What's the best way to store a Framework/API key for an iOS/Mac project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, api-key

As an example let's take the google api, you need a key for your app in order to start using the framework correctly.

Because I don't want the key to be explicitly available in a configuration file inside the .ipa, I'm specifying the api key in one of my implementation files, something like:

```
#define kGoogleAPIKey = @"XXXXX"
```

for further use in that class.

Is this the best way to do this in terms of security? If not, which alternatives do I have?

Thanks in advance!